# Sombrero Snapchat Winter Bash

Tags: soporte, winterbash-2016

Tengo una duda, acabo de recibir el sombrero Snapchat para una pregunta que se hizo hace 2 días y respondí hace dos días, pero hasta hoy no he tenido más de 3 votos y se ha aceptado hoy.

Mi duda es la siguiente: la respuesta debe ser aceptada antes de los 30 minutos de ser formulada la pregunta?  o es un bug lo que me ha sucedido?

Comment: Se debe responder antes de los 30 minutos.. las otras variables no están relacionadas con el tiempo.

Comment: Por ciero.. es insalubre obsesionarse con los sombreros. XD-

Comment: muchas gracias!! jajajaj ya lo se, pero este me lo han dado sin buscarlo y me ha parecido raro y creía que era un bug o algo